# how to properly set a $scope var after successfull ajax request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm working with symfony and AngularJs 1.6.8 and Symfony 3.4. I have the next configuration:

> base.html.twig

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="CeocApp" ng-controller="CeocController">
//css for the app
<link id="ng_load_plugins_before"/>
//more ccs for the app
<body>
....
<div class="row" ui-view></div>
....
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular/angular.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js') }}"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js') }}"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/ceoc/angular_app/ceoc-angular-app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> ceoc-app.js

```
var CeocApp = angular.module('CeocApp', [
    'ui.router',
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "oc.lazyLoad",
    "ngSanitize"
]).config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
}]);

CeocApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "../templates/dashboard.html",
            controller: "DashboardController as dashboard",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'CeocApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                        files: [
                            '../assets/ceoc/angular_app/controllers/dashboard-controller.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

}]);
```

dashboard-controller.js is a controller that works but there are the problems:

**Problem 1:**$http.get(Rountin.generate('route_name')) doesn't work.

When I run the app the controller is loaded and all before that $http.get() request works but the code after that doesn't()

```
angular.module('CeocApp').controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $rootScope.pageTitle = 'Dashboard';
    $scope.total = 2500;
    alert('this line will be reached');
    $http.get(Routing.generate('ceoc.dashboard')).then(function (data) {
        $scope.total = 10000 
    }, function (data) {
    });
    alert('this line will never be reached');
}]);
```

**Problem 2:** $.get doesn't let me change the $scope value.

When I change $http.get() for $.get() it works and the ajax request is made but the $scope.total value is not modified.

```
angular.module('CeocApp').controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $rootScope.pageTitle = 'Dashboard';
    $scope.total = 2500;

    $.get(Routing.generate('ceoc.dashboard')).success(function (data) {
        alert('request successfull');
        $scope.total = 200; //this value won't be setted
    }).then(function () {
        $scope.total = 6000;
    });

$scope.total = '879';//this value will be setted
}]);
```

> The server response

```
{"retrasadas":5,"total":10,"en_tiempo":5}
```

My question is how can I set properly a $scope.anyvar value after a successfull ajax request? (with $ or $http)
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Coec`'s handleAjax function and it's callback parameter:

```
Ceoc.handleAjax(Routing.generate('ceoc.dashboard'), "GET", function (data) {
  $scope.total = data.total;
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work $scope.apply() is not a function and $scope.$apply() does nothing. the same with $rootScope

Comment: @JuanI.MoralesPestana Oops, apologies. Have you tried it without `$scope.$apply()`? any changes in functionality?

Comment: witout the $apply() is the same I had before and still not setting the $scope.total value so the template is empty when I do {[{ total }]} (ti shows {[{ total }]}).

Comment: re-edit your post and add the deleted part. Now is working with $scope.$apply()(I don't know why). My mistake.. I'll show you the code:

`Ceoc.handleAjax(Routing.generate('ceoc.dashboard'), "GET", function (data) {

        $scope.total = data.total;
        $scope.$apply();
    });`

handleAjax is a function which makes the ajax request and then de callback success function is the third parameter and all works fine. Alson works as stand alone code(such as $.ajax or $.get). Update your post in order to vote and select your answer

Comment: Okay thank you @JuanI.MoralesPestana ! What a team we are